# Can a server generate traffic without load?

Tags: traffic

On the server I'm building my app, I have access to the cli. The administrator says that the server I'm working on is used to generate a lot of traffic, in order to flood another server. Lately, I have my console open as long I work on my server, ad besides my work, i didn't notice anything suspicious.

I have top utility running on a console, and everything looks fine. Server load is 0.00 as long as I don't work on the server.

I don't have access to any traffic tool to see if my server generates traffic. Can be any traffic be generated, as long the server load is 0.00??

Comment: If you are not the administrator of this server then it's not your job to find out what *might* be going on this machine, and you will be lacking the necessary tools and privileges to do so.

Answer (score 7):

> Can be any traffic be generated, as long the server load is 0.00??

Absolutally. It takes virtually no CPU effort to generate a ping flood to other servers, or to download giantic amounts of traffic. Especially if it's a proper server with TCP Offload.

However, if you're not the administrator, then you need to ask the admin to tell you what's wrong, rather than figure it out yourself, because it's unlikely you'll have the required priveliges.